# PHP - Syntax [array / variable]

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I want to use `stripos()` to filter a variable `$background` , if characters found return the keys value as `$background` ;

`if(stripos($background, $color) !== false) { $background = the value of keys in $color } else { $Background = 'No Color Found'};`

```
$color = array (
         'R' => "Red",
         'Y' => "Yellow",
         '$bgcolor' => array (
                       '#ffffd0' => "Yellow",
                       '#ddffdd' => "Green", ));
```

The variable $bgcolor is defined previously and returns hexadecimal color code.
Is the above syntax correct ?

Comment: where is the if condition of else. may be there should be error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `double quotes` for `variable key`. Strings with `single quotes` are ignoring variables.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain;');

$x = 'check';

$str = "$x";

echo $str, PHP_EOL;

$str = '$x';

echo $str, PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Shows:

```
check
$x
```

---

For the rest part of code you`ve provided, I guess you want something like this:

```
<?php
//header('Content-Type: text/plain;');

$background = '#ffffd0';

$color = array (
        'R' => "Red",
        'Y' => "Yellow",
        '#ffffd0' => "Yellow",
        '#ddffdd' => "Green"
    );

$result = array_key_exists($background, $color) ? $color[$background] : 'not set' ;

echo $result;
?>
```

Shows:

```
Yellow
```

Comment: Thanks. Will do.. using double quotes for "$bgcolor" ( a variable ) will work ?